# ERC-721 testing with JS - ReferenceError: use is not defined

Tags: solidity, truffle, javascript

I am following this tutorial: https://youtu.be/YPbgjPPC1d0
Got stuck at 34:47. This is the code I have written:

```
const Color = artifacts.require('./Color.sol')

require('chai')
use(require('chai-as-promised'))
should()

contract('Color', (accounts) => {
let contract

describe('deployment', async () => {
    it('deploys successfully', async () => {
contract = await Color.deployed()
const address = contract.address
console.log(address)
assert.notEqual(address, '')
    })
})
})
```

Everything seems to match the video, but after using `truffle test`
Using network 'development'.

```
Compiling .\src\contracts\ERC721Full.sol...
ReferenceError: use is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:/Users/Public/Dapp University/nft/test/Color.test.js:4:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at loader (C:\Users\Public\Dapp University\nft\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (C:\Users\Public\Dapp University\nft\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at C:\Users\BeAWhale\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:231:27
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (C:\Users\BeAWhale\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:228:14)
    at Mocha.run (C:\Users\BeAWhale\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:536:10)
    at C:\Users\BeAWhale\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-core\lib\test.js:118:1
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
Truffle v5.0.5 (core: 5.0.5)
Node v14.17.5
```

Has anyone had similar problem or knows how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the following lines:

```
require('chai')
use(require('chai-as-promised'))
should()
```

These should be chained calls, and so should re-written as:

```
require('chai')
  .use(require('chai-as-promised'))
  .should()
```

Comment: Wow how did I miss that...? Thank you!